# How frequently do "Tag stats" pages get updated?

Tags: tags, support

I believe the [*Tag Stats*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers) are not updated immediately when an answer is first upvoted. They seem to be updated every few hours. So my question is: What is the "frequency of updation" of Tag Stats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by-design, this page is heavily cached.

At the moment there is about a 15 minute cache interval (depending on the tag), in future I am looking at only updating that page daily (when that happens I will make sure some text in the page explains that)

It runs some very expensive queries so we need caching.

Answer (score 3):

The change that waffles mentioned in his answer has taken place. The bottom of the tag stats pages now include this statement:

> Only non community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals (updated daily)